# JOOQ: Batch execute multiple transaction

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have to insert same record in 2 different tables in an atomic way. I am using JOOQ transaction.

```
        dslContext.transactionResultAsync { configuration ->
            val context = configuration.dsl()
            context
                .insertInto(table1)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()

            context.insertInto(table2)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()
```

However I have several 100 thousands of such records. So instead of executing 100K queries I want to execute 1 big batch query. JOOQ supports batching on the query as

```
   val batch = dslContext.batch(
            dslContext.insertInto(table2)
                .set(dummyRecord)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(dummyRecord)
   )

   records.forEach{batch.bind(it)}
   batch.execute()
}
```

Now I can't seem to locate a way to batch multiple transactions.

**Update**

I found following

```kotlin
dslContext.batchedResult { config ->
  config.transactionResultAsync { configuration ->
            val context = configuration.dsl()
            context
                .insertInto(table1)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()

            context.insertInto(table2)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()
   }
}
```

But I think it is not the same. Batched connection simply batches the SQL statements generically and doesn't actually use prepared statements for inserts. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can place your "update" as an answer to your own question. This is explicitly encouraged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about batching compared to individual queries. From a transaction perspective, these two are equivalent:

```kotlin
// No batching:
dslContext.transactionResultAsync { configuration ->
    val context = configuration.dsl()
    context.insertInto(...).execute();
    context.insertInto(...).execute();
}

// Batching
dslContext.transactionResultAsync { configuration ->
    val context = configuration.dsl()
    context.batch(...).execute();
    context.batch(...).execute();
}
```

Comment: But having multiple batches in inside a transaction would be bad no? It means that all 100K records will be created in the same transaction. I need other way around, batch multiple transactions

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: Why is it bad to create 100k records in a transaction? What does it even mean to "batch a transaction"?

Comment: I am ok to fail to create few records rather than fail to create 100K records. I just need the same record to be updated in 2 different tables in a transaction. And need 100K such records to be persisted.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: But what does "batching transactions" even mean? You can't batch transactions in the sense of sending such instructions over the wire via JDBC. Did you mean to run this logic in a procedural loop on the server? jOOQ supports creating stored procedures or anonymous procedural blocks: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements, if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I didn't know that we can not have multiple transactions  batched together. What is the standard way to avoid sending 100K transactions separately over wire because due to network latency it might be too time consuming.

Will batched connection work?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: I'm not sure what the problem is to create 100k records in a single batch. Are you measuring things, or are you just guessing? If it really *is* a problem, how about creating 10k records in 10 batches? jOOQ has an API for this kind of throttling: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-api/

Answer (score 0):

I found following

```kotlin
dslContext.batchedResult { config ->
  config.transactionResultAsync { configuration ->
            val context = configuration.dsl()
            context
                .insertInto(table1)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()

            context.insertInto(table2)
                .set(record)
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .set(record)
                .execute()
   }
}
```

But I think it is not the same. Batched connection simply batches the SQL statements generically and doesn't actually use prepared statements for inserts. Any other suggestions?